# Plotly change negative y axis values. e.g. change -1 to (1)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to try and plot this [Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Agq.png), so that for instead of having a -2 y value it would be (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `(2)` is a string. Since you cannot mix data types together for the tick text, you will need change each of the y-axis tick labels to be strings, not just -2, meaning you will need map the tick value of -2 to tick text which is the string '(2)', 0 to '0', 2 to '2', and so on... I admit that it's ugly, but I cannot think of another workaround.

More information about tick text and text values can be found in the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## recreate some random timeseries data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range("2021-01-01","2022-01-01", freq="d"),
    'x1':np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=366),
    'x2':np.random.uniform(low=4.0, high=8.0, size=366)
})

## plot your data on the fig
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df.date,
        y=df.x1,
        mode='lines'
        )
    )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df.date,
        y=df.x2,
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(color='black', dash='dash')
        )
    )

## map each of the tickvals to the desired ticktext 
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=[-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
        ticktext=['(2)', '0', '2', '4', '6', '8']
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]